# How to deploy maven generated jar along with dependency directory to Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

This is how my *Maven* target directory looks like:

```
target
|_ my-app-0.0.1.jar
|_ lib
```

When I run `mvn release:peform`, the jar file gets deployed onto the *Nexus* repository.

Any ideas how I can have the lib directory also on Nexus? Can I *tar* them as part of the deploy process?

I'm facing unresolvable problems with the `maven-assembly-plugin`, hence I need to have the dependencies outside the jar (which I achieved using `maven-dependency-plugin`).

Comment: @SergeyPauk good to know that the `maven-assembly-plugin` is the standard solution in this situation. In my case however, I have **local jars** that don't match the same named jars in maven (despite the version match). The `maven-dependency-plugin` lets me copy the jars I want into the lib directory. It also copies the maven dependencies into the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a tar.gz or zip archve with the desired structure instead of of creating a jar-with-dependencies. That artifact should be attached and therefore also be deployed to Nexus.